# how to sort an array in descending order in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, sql-order-by

Newly-entered products are displayed in the last row. If there is a large amount, it is difficult to see at the bottom. How can I change the new display to the top. Thank you!

```
$barcodes_ary = explode(',', $barcodes);
    $barcodes_hash = array ();
    foreach ($barcodes_ary as $b) {
        if (array_key_exists($b, $barcodes_hash)) {
            $barcodes_hash[$b] += 1;
        } else {
            $barcodes_hash[$b] = 1;
        }
    }
    foreach ($barcodes_hash as $b => $amount) {
        if ($barcodes_ary == array(''))continue; 
        $ary = get_sql("SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Barcode='$b' Order by ProductName");
                    if ( count($ary) == 0 ) {
            continue;
        } 
        $pid  = $ary[0]['ProductID'];
        $pn   = $ary[0]['ProductName'];
        $unit = $ary[0]['UnitID'];

        $ary2 = get_sql("SELECT UnitName FROM Units WHERE UnitID = '$unit'");
        $unit = $ary2[0]['UnitName'];

        ?>
        <TR>
        <TD><? echo "$pn"; ?></TD>
        <TD>
        <INPUT TYPE=hidden NAME=productid<?=$pid?>        VALUE='<?=$pid?>'>    
        <?
        $candidates = array();
        for($i=1; $i <= DropDownMaxValue; $i++) {
            $candidates[]=$i;
        }
```

//update
I use another way to solve the problem. Just display the same product.

```
function push_barcode() {
// alert('barcode pushing');
b  = document.form1.barcode;
bs = document.form1.barcodes;
if (bs.value == "") {
    bs.value = b.value;
} else { // ?? 111,333,444,... ???
    bs.value = b.value;
}
```

}

Comment: Why not just reverse the array?

Comment: refer https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Barcode='$b' Order by ProductName DESC"` `DESC` will start at the end and order the query backwards...

Comment: @Premlatha krsort($ary);  not working

Comment: @dalelandry $ary = get_sql("SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Barcode='$b' Order by ProductName DESC"); not working.

Comment: You're trying to get the results of the `$ary[0]['ProductName'];` correct? Do you get results if you var_dump this, it is you just want to fully reverse the results correct?

Comment: Do you get results if you var_dump($ary[0]['ProductName']);

Comment: @dalelandry yes. I just want fullt reverse the result. Or just display 1 result is fine. But I don't know how to remove the array, coz I am new here.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you should be able to get the count using the `keys` values returned in reverse in brackets with the array.

Try the following and see if it works for you...

```php
$ProductName = $ary[0]['ProductName'];
//--> get the count of your array
$count = count($ProductName);
//--> define an output variable to hold values
$output = null;
$i = 0;
//--> reduce count by one as key values start at 0 and count starts at 1
$count = $count - 1;
//--> subtraction and addition of $count by one to reduce warning 
//--> of `undefined offset` for index on mismatched key values
while($count + 1){
        //--> concatenate the values into a variable for display
        $output .= $ProductName[$count];
        //--> or push the reversed values back into an array 
        $product_name[$i] = $ProductName[$count];
        //--> $product_name should now hold your values in reverse use a foreach 
        // use a foreach to display values in your table
        $count--;
        $i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean add here?


$ary = get_sql("SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Barcode='$b' Order by ProductName");


//you code here?


         if ( count($ary) == 0 ) {
            continue;
        }

Comment: Basically you are restructuring your array by declaring a new array and reversing the key values by using the count decremented as you run the loop and push the values back in.